# Can you run glassfish with JRockit?

Tags: java, glassfish, sun, jrockit

Has anyone tried running glassfish with JRockit? I see some references saying it's not possible but they are very outdated. Anyone tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible in Windows. We do this for several production, public facing, web apps.

We had to remove some default Glassfish JVM flags, since they don't apply to JRockit (this is optional, it's just that the start up warnings really annoyed me), and tune the JVM a little differently, but other than that we have not run into any issues.

(We use SJSAS though, but I don't think that should make a difference)

Here are the versions of the software we are using:

- Windows Server 2003
- Sun Java System Application Server 9.1_01
- JRockit R27.5.0 (Java 6)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there was a problem on windows: https://glassfish.dev.java.net/servlets/ReadMsg?list=dev&msgNo=878. Linux and Solaris seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

The recently released GlassFish 3.0.1 states on http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/glassfish/index.html

> Update JDK support:
>
> HotSpot JDK
> testing/compliance updated to HotSpot
> JDK 1.6.0_20
>
> Added Oracle JRockit 6
> Update 17 R28.0.0+ support

Answer (score 0):

there only one porblem when you startup the server...but this is solved by using:

Work around;
Comment out following 2 lines in domain.xml.

```
 <!--
    <jvm-options>-XX:+LogVMOutput</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-XX:LogFile=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/jvm.log</jvm-options>
 -->
```

from: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-11986